# Submit Dojo NumberTextBox with leading zeros

Tags: dojo

I'm new in Dojo Toolkit and I want to submit a NumberTextBox field in my form keeping leading zeros. Is that possible ?
I'm using the latest version of Dojo.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood your question, if you would like send number like `00,01`, and now get `0,01`, my suggestions will be:

- use `ValidationTextBox` instead `Number...`, and attach to its properly regExp
- use pattern properties: `pattern:'#,#00.00'` - to get 2 leading zeros.

Comment: Something like that, but without dots or commas. I tried the pattern property without success.